# Drawing Ellipsoids in Asymptote; Camera too Close

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I am trying to draw a set of Ellipsoids in `Asymptote` which are given by an symmetric positive definite matrix or in other words by three vectors `v1,v2,v3` of length 1 forming an ONB (the ellipsoids main axes) and their lengths `l1,l2,l3`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyTest}
import three;
import settings;

surface ellipsoid(triple v1,triple v2,triple v3,real l1,real l2, real l3, triple pos=O) {
    transform3 T = identity4;
    T[0][0] = l1*v1.x;
    T[1][0] = l1*v1.y;
    T[2][0] = l1*v1.z;
    T[0][1] = l2*v2.x;
    T[1][1] = l2*v2.y;
    T[2][1] = l2*v2.z;
    T[0][2] = l3*v3.x;
    T[1][2] = l3*v3.y;
    T[2][2] = l3*v3.z;
    T[0][3] = pos.x;
    T[1][3] = pos.y;
    T[2][3] = pos.z;
    return T*unitsphere;
}

size(9cm);

currentprojection=perspective(4.5,4,-11,Z, (4.5,4,0));

draw(ellipsoid( (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, O), rgb(0,1,0));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

The function should be able to scale and shift the unitsphere and hence creating an ellipsoid given by the above values and a center point `pos`, where the third to last line is an MWE for a green ellipsoid.

The `perspective` should look from below into the middle of all my ellipsoids (yep  `9x8`field here).

However the above Code resembles a `Camera too close` error, even if i move it far far away (replace `-11`by `-100` say).

What's the reason for that? Any ideas?

One thing i noticed by creating the MWE: Removing `l3` from the `transform3 T`, i.e. keeping `v3` at unit length makes this file compile. Nevertheless i need to scale all 3 axes (which in general are of course no the unit axis as in this MWE).

Comment: Interesting observation: It works for `l3=0.595`, but not for `l3=0.59`.

Comment: If you use the default perspective projection, you can get down to `l3=0.55` without error, but still get the same `camera too close` error with `l3=0.5`.

Comment: Moving the camera much farther away does not appear to make much difference, but switching to an orthographic projection does.

Comment: Intersting observations! I'll check tomorrow for the whole field, whether the orthographic will look okay, i took the prespective just because i was used to that :) I won't mind the orthographic if it works with all its occlusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Final solution**

The problem is that by setting `T = identity4`, you are really making `T` an alias for `identity4`, so that changes to `T` are reflected in `identity4`. It's surprising this does not screw up more things than it does.

A correct version may be obtained by initializing `T` to be a *copy* of `identity4`:

```
transform3 T = copy(identity4);
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyTest}
import three;
import settings;

surface ellipsoid(triple v1,triple v2,triple v3,real l1,real l2, real l3, triple pos=O) {
    transform3 T = copy(identity4);
    T[0][0] = l1*v1.x;
    T[1][0] = l1*v1.y;
    T[2][0] = l1*v1.z;
    T[0][1] = l2*v2.x;
    T[1][1] = l2*v2.y;
    T[2][1] = l2*v2.z;
    T[0][2] = l3*v3.x;
    T[1][2] = l3*v3.y;
    T[2][2] = l3*v3.z;
    T[0][3] = pos.x;
    T[1][3] = pos.y;
    T[2][3] = pos.z;
    return T*unitsphere;
}

size(9cm);

currentprojection=perspective(4.5,4,-11,Z, (4.5,4,0));

draw(ellipsoid( (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, O), rgb(0,1,0));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

### The following edits are maintained for historical reasons only.

**Update 2**

Here is a truly minimal (non-)working example of the problem (as an asy file, to show that the issue is intrinsic to Asymptote and not related to the TeX embedding):

```
import three;
transform3 T = identity4;
T[2][2] = 0.4;
draw(unitsphere);
```

The result is an error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/asymptote/three.asy: 2903.30: camera too close
```

I have [filed a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/bugs/189/).

**Update**

After further research, I've found something truly bizarre. Somehow, the mere fact of computing `T` as you do is causing the error, regardless of whether the computation is used for anything.

The error shows up for the definition

```
surface ellipsoid(triple v1,triple v2,triple v3,real l1,real l2, real l3, triple pos=O) {
    transform3 T = identity4;
    T[0][0] = l1*v1.x;
    T[1][0] = l1*v1.y;
    T[2][0] = l1*v1.z;
    T[0][1] = l2*v2.x;
    T[1][1] = l2*v2.y;
    T[2][1] = l2*v2.z;
    T[0][2] = l3*v3.x;
    T[1][2] = l3*v3.y;
    T[2][2] = l3*v3.z;
    T[0][3] = pos.x;
    T[1][3] = pos.y;
    T[2][3] = pos.z;

    /*transform3*/ T = scale(l1, l2, l3);
    return T*unitsphere;
}
```

but not for the definition

```
surface ellipsoid(triple v1,triple v2,triple v3,real l1,real l2, real l3, triple pos=O) {
  /*transform3 T = identity4;
    T[0][0] = l1*v1.x;
    T[1][0] = l1*v1.y;
    T[2][0] = l1*v1.z;
    T[0][1] = l2*v2.x;
    T[1][1] = l2*v2.y;
    T[2][1] = l2*v2.z;
    T[0][2] = l3*v3.x;
    T[1][2] = l3*v3.y;
    T[2][2] = l3*v3.z;
    T[0][3] = pos.x;
    T[1][3] = pos.y;
    T[2][3] = pos.z;
  */
    transform3 T = scale(l1, l2, l3);
    return T*unitsphere;
}
```

These two should give exactly the same result; the only difference is that the first one does the computation of `T` (and then overwrites it), while the second does not do the computation.

Bottom line: I'm clueless as to where this error is coming from.

---

The problem appears to be that you are incorrectly constructing the `transform3` matrix, with the result that the sphere is being blown up to something astronomically huge. So the error thrown by Asymptote is legitimate.

I have not gone through the reasoning about how the matrix is constructed, but I have two pieces of evidence that, taken together, strongly suggest the my conclusion.

First: For your particular test case, the major axes are simply the standard basis, so--if I understand correctly what you are doing--this example ought to give the same result if you define `ellipsoid` function by

```
surface ellipsoid(triple v1,triple v2,triple v3,real l1,real l2, real l3, triple pos=O) {
    transform3 T = scale(l1, l2, l3);
    return T*unitsphere;
}
```

However, with this definition, the file compiles with no problems. So there is almost certainly an error in your logic defining the `transform3`.

Second: Although it initially appears that moving the viewpoint farther away makes no difference, this is not quite correct--it's just that very small changes in `l3` can make astronomical differences in the size of the ellipsoid. But I was able to find a boundary case by setting `l3=0.591`:

```
currentprojection=perspective((4.5,4,-11), up=Z, (4.5,4,0));
draw(ellipsoid( (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), 0.2, 0.3, 0.591, O), rgb(0,1,0));
```

does not compile, but if you multiply the camera distance by tenfold

```
currentprojection=perspective(10*(4.5,4,-11), up=Z, (4.5,4,0));
draw(ellipsoid( (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), 0.2, 0.3, 0.591, O), rgb(0,1,0));
```

it does compile.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, i reduced the basis to the unit vectors for the MWE, a more realistic call would be like `ellipsoid( (0.26865,-0.064339,0.96109), (-0.9537,-0.15783,0.25602), (-0.13522,0.98537,0.10376), 0.51182, 0.2709, 0.24786, (0,0,0) ),` - but the basis is normalized (by MatLab). Concerning `transform3` you may be right, i couldn't find any documentation of the internal definition of that data type...

Comment: @Ronny: I assumed that the `scale` option would not be sufficient for you in general, but it made a useful comparison for the MWE. However, as you will see in my update, I am retracting my original answer--there is something truly bizarre going on here. Somehow the mere fact of computing `T` as you do is causing the error, regardless of whether the computation is used. And that makes no sense at all.

Comment: But in your Update you're performing the scaling _twice_ once in the lines of my definition and once using scale? Maybe the error really already occurs when _defining_ `T` like I do, not when _applying_ it to `unitsphere`. But i couldnÄt find any other way to define a `T`, when you know the transformation matrix and the shift.

Comment: @Ronny: The second definition should overwrite the first, not be composed with it. In any case, I agree with you that it *ought* to be possible to define `T` as you do, and it makes no sense that it is causing an error--especially this particular error.

Comment: Maybe you're right. At least the whole behaviour is strange.

Comment: Yay! You found the problem. Nevertheless it's really not a bug. I wanted to ask that on SF and did some research. Actually (and i don't know why they keep that) `transform T = identity4;` will give you the reference to the identity (in R3 w/ homogeneous coordinates), which will mess up a lot of things. While `copy(...)`; looks a little clumsy, the way it's used in `three.asy` is actually `transform3 T = identity(4);`, which gives you a copy of the identity. Somehow I forgot the `()` and surprisingly that messes things up like... alot.